# Android Button Bar in Holo

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an Android app that uses the Holo theme when available and falls back to the black theme when it isn't available. I am accomplishing this by using the `values`, `values-v11`, and `values-14` folders.

I have an activity that I would like to use the `?android:attr/buttonBarStyle` and `?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle` styles but I am unsure how to fall back to a different style when they are not available (such as `@android:style/ButtonBar`). Here is my layout for reference.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonArea"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button One" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button Two" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using two separate layout files, one located in the `layout` folder and one located in `layout-v11`. They are almost the same except that they contain different values for the `style` attribute.

The first one looks like this (in `layout`):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonArea"
    style="@style/buttonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/buttonBarButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/buttonBarButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The second one looks like this (in `layout-v11`):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonArea"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am not completely satisfied with this approach because of the amount of duplicate information. I would like to find a way to use `?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle` as a parent style, but I couldn't find a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I'm a little bit late, but this is how I solved it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    style="@style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/accountSpinner"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/login" />
    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button2"
        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

with this styles:

```
<style name="ButtonBarButton">
</style>

<style name="ButtonBar" parent="@android:style/ButtonBar">
</style>
```

and for v11:

```
<style name="ButtonBarButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonBar" parent="@android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
</style>
```

Comment: How did you know these attrs map to Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless and Holo.Light.ButtonBar.AlertDialog?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember. I think it was a mixture of "try and error", code completion and stackoverflow